# onclick dropdown menu with fallback to on hover, work on more than one menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, hover

Been trying to get it so that I have a dropdown menu dropdown on click, and if you do not have javascript enabled, so it uses regular mouseover.

However, I can not get it to work on more than one menu item, so that it is now so click on a menu, so go all down with the same content.

What am I doing wrong? See the example below.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/H3KRk/1/)

**CODE:**

```
$(function() {
    // Clickable Dropdown
    $('.nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
    $('.nav .js ul').hide();
    $('.nav .js').click(function(e) {
        $('.nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
        $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
        $('.clicker2').toggleClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        if ($('.nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
            $('.nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
            $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
            $('.clicker2').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overly complicating things. All you need is something like this:

```
$(".nav .js").find(".clicker").on("click", function() {
   $('.nav .js ul').hide();
   $(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
```

See your updated fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/H3KRk/3/](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20140320035008/http://jsfiddle.net:80/H3KRk/3/)

Moreover, you need to have at least one common class for your anchors which are menus. For purposes other than menu, use more classes if needed. In your example, the class should be `clicker` on all menu anchors.

**Update**:

In order to hide menu when clicked outside the menu itself, you need to get the target (using event delegation on document) and then apply this routine to that target anchor only. Something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var $elem = $(e.target);
    if ($elem.hasClass('clicker')) {
       $('.nav .js ul').not($elem.next('ul')).hide();
       $elem.next("ul").slideToggle();
    } else {
       $('.nav .js ul').hide();
    }
});
```

See updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/H3KRk/4/**

**Update 2**:

Now, for your fallback to css. You are on the right track. Just a little tweak to your css.

See this updated 2: **http://jsfiddle.net/H3KRk/5/**

You need to apply css on inner ul when hovering on li:

```
.nav > .no-js > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

instead of `.nav .no-js:hover ul` as it was in your code.

Hope that helps complete all of your problems.

Comment: That's not quite right, for the hover is the same content, and how do you do that the menu will go up again when you click on the menu link or outside?

Comment: @LarsHolmqvist: there you go, updated the answer. i thought you would be able to figure that out by yourself.

Comment: Now it's the next right, though, so when you turn off javascript in the browser so the menu will shift to onhover instead. What it does, however, so certain people the same content in both sub menus (menu shows one content in both).

Comment: @LarsHolmqvist: updated my answer. come on lars! i thought you would have found it out yourself after looking at the javascript code! just look at selectors carefully. what is the target?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead -

```
$(function() {
    // Clickable Dropdown
    $('.nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
    $('.nav .js ul').hide();
    $('.nav .js li').click(function(e) {
        $('.nav .js ul').hide();
        $('.nav .js li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(200);
        $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
        if ($('.nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('.nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
        $('.nav .js li a').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Also you dont need to define 'clicker' and 'clicker1' class in html.

For non js browser you can use @abhitalks code -

```
.nav > .no-js > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Please read his answer. I can't comment because of low reputation. thanks.

Comment: Now it's the next right, though, so when you turn off javascript in the browser so the menu will shift to onhover instead.

What it does, however, so certain people the same content in both sub menus (menu shows one content in both).